# customAnimation when calling popBackStack on a FragmentManager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

In my activity, with the touch of a button, I replace the current fragment with a new fragment using a custom animation, like in this example.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_anomalie:
            Fragment contentFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content);

            if(contentFragment instanceof AnomalieListFragment)
            {
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out);
                anomalieFragment = new AnomalieListFragment();
                ft.replace(R.id.content, anomalieFragment);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();
            }

    ...
```

However, [popping back the stack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack()) doesn't show any animation.
Is there a way to specify a custom animation like we do in a FragmentTransaction with the [setCustomAnimations](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setCustomAnimations(int,%20int)) method?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

After further reading of the documentation, I found that using [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setCustomAnimations(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) signature of `setCustomAnimation` allowed the animation to be played when pressing the back button or calling `getFragmentManager().popBackStack();`

I modified my code like this

```
...
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out, android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out);
anomalieFragment = new AnomalieListFragment();
ft.replace(R.id.content, anomalieFragment);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
...
```

Comment: Thanks this works great. What makes this code work is the `setCustomAnimations` method called with the 4 parameter overload. The 2 param one does not animate on `popBackStack`.

Comment: Note, .setCustomAnimations needs to be before .replace.

Comment: @Goldorak84 This is the solution. If you click on the setCustomAnimation property to view source code you can see that the function looks like public FragmentTransaction setCustomAnimations(int enter, int exit, int popEnter, int popExit)  ----> with other words, they explicitly state that the last two params are in fact pop animation resources