# how to add animation in android to popBackStack?

Tags: android, android-studio

i have a fragment i'm popping back into another fragment like this:

```
 final FragmentManager fm = getParentFragmentManager();
 fm.popBackStack(myFirstFragment.LOG_TAG, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

right now the fragment just disappeared, instead of going back with a transition

how do I add a customer animation for that popping back?

Answer (score 1):

You can do so, by simply calling the .setCustomAnimations Method from the FragmentTransaction.

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out, android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out);
```

For custom animations create a `fade_in.xml` and `fade_out.xml` and call it instead of `android.R.animatior.fade_in` and `android.R.animatior.fade_out`

**fade_in.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
   <alpha
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromAlpha="0.1"
        android:toAlpha="1.0">
    </alpha>
</set>
```

**fade_out.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    <alpha
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.1" >
    </alpha>
</set>
```

For further information look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550643/customanimation-when-calling-popbackstack-on-a-fragmentmanager).

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the pop animations as you add your fragment to the stack.

**JAVA**

```
 Fragment fragment = new FragmentB();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .setCustomAnimations(
            R.anim.slide_in,  // enter
            R.anim.fade_out,  // exit
            R.anim.fade_in,   // popEnter
            R.anim.slide_out  // popExit
        )
        .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
```

**KOTLIN**

```
val fragment = FragmentB()
supportFragmentManager.commit {
    setCustomAnimations(
        enter = R.anim.slide_in,
        exit = R.anim.fade_out,
        popEnter = R.anim.fade_in,
        popExit = R.anim.slide_out
    )
    replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
    addToBackStack(null)
}
```

for more information read :
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/animate#kotlin